# Finding out how a website is coded

Tags: html, web

I'm trying to figure out how to program a website that looks very similar to http://www.renthop.com/.

I'm new to web coding, so I'm not really sure where to start.  For example, is it Java or HTML? Or both?  I really like how its setup, the responsiveness and smoothness of it. I just want to make sure I start off in the right direction in terms of choosing the right language etc.

If anyone has any idea of what this is based on it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks - KC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server-side code is PHP, the front-end is built off of the jQuery and jQuery-UI javascript libraries and a series of third-party plugins. The final product is a dynamic HTML application.

Comment: Start with javascript and PHP.

Comment: You're a legend. As I'm sure you've guessed, I have no idea how to build a website...

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere. A good place to begin is to right click the page and hit "view source."

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to launch your website? If so, creating a website from HTML would only make a website on your local hard drive, not public. You're going to need a domain name and hosting to make it public.

HTML is a markup language for formatting websites, but you can still create a website out of it. Not public, as I said above.

CSS is rulesets for telling the browser how to display the HTML formatted content.  It is also not a programming language in the same way HTML is, although it can be a lot more powerful.

Javascript is a programming language.  You use it to make the website interactive.  Get Firebug or a similar add-on for Firefox, or just right click and 'Inspect Element' in Chrome to see the javascript for more detail on what javascript does.

AJAX is an extension of javascript to get data from the web server and update the page with it, without having to refresh the page.

PHP is code commonly used server side to interact with the filesystem and databases and output HTML.  You can also use python, perl, .NET and a handful of other languages/frameworks to do this.

MySQL is a database.